# Split a conditional expression programmatically

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am looking for a known way (if any) to split a long conditional expression into independent statements.

For example, I have this long expression:

```
*IF ( 
   ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'python' 
     *OR *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'java' ) 
   *AND 
   ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 1 
    *OR *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 2 )
 )
```

I want to get all the possible combinations for this statement to be true. Manually I can iterate a first time and get this:

```
*IF (
   ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'python' ) 
   *AND ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 1 
     *OR *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 2) )
*IF ( 
  ( *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'java' ) 
  *AND ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 1 
    *OR *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 2) )
```

And a second time I will have the full set of combinations:

```
*IF ( ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'python' ) 
   *AND ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 1 ) )
*IF ( ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'python' ) 
   *AND ( *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 2 ) )
*IF ( ( *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'java' ) 
   *AND ( *VALUE K01_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 1 ) )
*IF ( ( *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Name *EQ 'java' ) 
   *AND ( *VALUE K02_PROCESS_COUNTS.Process_Count *LT 2 ) )
```

I was thinking on doing this from scratch but I was wondering, is there any algorithm available for this type of operations? I have been searching for a while but I am unable to find it. I am working in Java, but any other language will work too.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you are perhaps not looking for a design pattern instead of an algorithm. Perhaps the state machine design pattern which falls into the category of strategy patterns might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern


Also as you are using Java you could try nested switch statements if you prefer that from the if else structure. http://www.java-examples.com/nested-switch-statements-example

Comment: Yes: any boolean expression can be expressed as a sum (OR) of products (AND). Basically, need to rewrite each sub-expression of the form A AND (B OR C) as (A AND B) OR (A AND C).

Comment: I.e., you want to convert a formula to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form .

Comment: Yes @DavidEisenstat, that is what I am looking for. I created a simple function that cover most of my cases [here](https://gist.github.com/miguelfc/34192a550a3b357f1f144a16eff26156), but I was looking for something more general if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to parse the statements and then apply a fairly simple recursive algorithm to expand the terms.

```
to expand L *AND R:
    for l in expand(L):
        for r in expand(R):
            yield l *AND r

to expand L *OR R:
    for l in expand(L):
        yield l
    for r in expand(R):
        yield r
```

See https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/misc/blob/master/2017-02-10/dnf.go for a complete implementation in Go. The implementation also parses `*NOT` and simplifies expressions involving it using De Morgan's laws.

Comment: Thanks David! I will try your approach.